# F# using inline: still fail to match different type for generic function

Tags: function, generics, f#, inline

I tried to use "inline" to define a function that would fit into different input parameter types:

```
> let x=2.0
- let inline f x=x+1
- f x;;

  f x;;
  --^

stdin(6,3): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int
but here has type
    float
```

I expect that after applying "inline" on f, I got a generic function call "f". but seems failed.
How to correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to use `genericOne` like so:

```
let inline f x = x + LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
```

This is because when you have used `1`, the compiler has infered that the function argument must be an `int` as you can only add `ints` to other `ints`

then you can call it with

```
> f 1;;
val it : int = 2
> f 1.0;;
val it : float = 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're adding `1` in your function. Because of that `x` has to be an `int`.

`inline` would work if you provide both sides of `+` as parameters:

```
> let inline f x y = x + y;;

val inline f :
  x: ^a -> y: ^b ->  ^c
    when ( ^a or  ^b) : (static member ( + ) :  ^a *  ^b ->  ^c)
```

As you can see, it's type is resolved as *any type with `+`*. You can use it to add two `int`s`or two`float`s together:

```
> f 1 2;;
val it : int = 3
> f 1. 2.;;
val it : float = 3.0
```

You can't however use it to add an `int` to a `float`:

```
> f 1. 2;;

  f 1. 2;;
  -----^

stdin(9,6): error FS0001: The type 'int' does not match the type 'float'
```